# filter page by multiple categories

Tags: categories, filter

I have a single channel with two different category groups. I want to filter the results by combining those groups.
So I could say show me all pet types = dogs & pet colours = brown.
I have the following code producing the two dropdowns but I'm trying to get a the page to reload with the filtered results.

````
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
  
    <select name="category[]">
        <option value="">filter by convention</option>
        {exp:channel:categories channel="convention" category_group="3"}
        <option value="1">{category_name}</option>
        {/exp:channel:categories}
    </select>
    <select name="category[]">
        <option value="">filter by Area</option>
        {exp:channel:categories channel="{ch}" category_group="4"}
        <option value="1">{category_name}</option>
        {/exp:channel:categories}
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are on EE7 you could do this with Pro Search (and if on an earlier version with Low Search. The way to go about this is described here: https://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples#categories-3